# VMware GNU C Compiler

Tags: 20.04, vmware

I have Ubuntu 20.04.
I am trying to open the VMware Player and it shows me this error:
[image]

I have tried: sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried installing gcc? You can install it with `sudo apt install gcc`

Comment: @cocomac yes I have tried

Comment: Try `sudo apt update && sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: 20.04 does not come with gcc 11 in the standard repos.  It might be easier to upgrade to 21.10 which does have gcc 11.2 than to locate a separate gcc 11 package.

Comment: @cocomac I have tried that not working

Comment: @ubfan1 but if I want to use 20.04 because is the LTS version and I am not confortable to change to 21.10 is it possible?

Comment: Wait six more days and the next LTS release, 22.04, will be out.

Comment: @ubfan1 ok thanks!

Comment: The Apr 14th release is the release candidate, with the official 22.04 release April 21st.  Of course, the daily builds are out now, but no support here on 22.04 until April 21st.